# Trying to set value on hidden parameter on click of submit button in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to set a parameter on a hidden field on click of submit button.

```
    $('.delete').on('click', function() {
        $('#id').val('1000');
    });
```

This is the hidden field:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="id" />
```

And this is one of my submit buttons:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Delete item" class="delete" />
```

However at the server the itemId field is empty.

Comment: The code you have should work fine. My guess is the problem lies elsewhere, either there is a javascript error preventing the value being set onclick, or your server side code is not retrieving the value correctly.

Comment: agree with above.  that code looks correct.  what error do you show?

Comment: I am getting an error on the server saying that no path matched the request.

Comment: can you show the code how you did to show the value at the server..?

Comment: check the "action" attribute of your form.  is that a valid url?

Comment: It works now, I had used the id attribute multiple times on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it by using Jquery .attr() function :

Change:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
$('#id').val('1000');
});
```

To:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
$('#id').attr('value','1000');
});
```